# Mirrored text in start menu and windows applications on laptop with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, start-menu, user-interface

I've got a very weird problem: text in start menu, windows settings and other windows applications is mirrored: it reads from right to left.

Even weirder is that text in windows search field, next to start button, is displayed correctly, but after opening the start menu it switches suddenly and becomes mirrored too.

I tried updating everything, restarting the system, creating another user and rotating the display, nothing worked as far.

It might be important, that this is an HP elitebook 850 g2  laptop with some software from HP, Intel and Radeon installed, but I tried killing those apps one by one and this also did not help. I'm running out of ideas. please help

I've recorded a video: [recording](https://youtu.be/Osjs78W6vVo)

Regards

Comment: Region selected in settings look correctly, ctrl+left shift changes nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First try DISM and SFC:**

Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup

DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth

SFC /SCANNOW

Restart when all the above is complete and test.

======

**If the above fails,** make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Windows Account.

If the Start Menu works in the new Profile, then you need to back up your user profile and re-create it.

Comment: Thank you very much